# Where is expressed the distance between particles for the formula of cross-section in an accelerator?

Tags: large-hadron-collider, scattering-cross-section

Let's consider the so-called Master formula, which expresses the cross-section of interaction between two protons, taking into account the parton density function and the intrinsic cross-sections between two partons, for example found [here](https://indico.cern.ch/event/208901/contributions/1501068/attachments/323332/450949/Maltoni_L4.pdf):

[image]

Where is the distance between the two particles that come in two opposite directions expressed?

Indeed, let's imagine two exact parallel beams of protons: one on earth, and one in another galaxy, the formula of cross-sections between the two protons seems to stay be the same, while from first principles, in this example, it should be exactly null: so where is the *distance* between the two incoming particles expressed in the formula ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not expressed anywhere in the cross section, because the cross section doesn't know anything about the beams. The cross section doesn't know anything about the specific experimental setup - the quantity that does is called the collider's [luminosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity_(scattering_theory)) and the total number of events you will detect is
$$ N = \sigma L_{\text{int}},$$
where $L_{\text{int}}$ is the time-integrated luminosity of the collider setup over the course of the experiment.

The computation of the luminosity of real-world collider setups is non-trivial. For an introduction see e.g. [*"Concept of luminosity"*](https://cds.cern.ch/record/941318/files/p361.pdf) [pdf link] by Herr and Muratori.